# Convert 1,000,000 to 1.0E6 In JavaScript

Tags: javascript, integer, double, type-conversion, parseint

I am wondering how I can convert 1,000,000 to 1.0E6 in JavaScript.
I'd like the complete opposite of the parseInt function?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1000000 and 1.0e6 is identically notation in javascript. Function parseInt(string[, radix])
 simply convert string to number by radix.
For back convert number to string you can use intValue.toString(radix)

Comment: I have a problem, its returning a different value than 1.0E6:

Comment: var x = 1000000;
var val = x.toExponential();
alert(val);

Comment: use can use var x = 1000000; var val = x.toExponential(1); console.log(val);

Comment: May I ask a question, what is radix?

Comment: radix like a base scale of notation

Comment: New problem... radix is not defined

Comment: radix is not a variable. it is a not required parameter in function

Answer (score 2):

Use [`toExponential`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toExponential) then modify the string as needed:

```
(1000000).toExponential()
"1e+6"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = 1200000;
var val = x.toExponential();
var val = val.replace("+", "");
alert(val);
```